# Write and Update record on Cassandra along with clustering columns

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

I have a notification table and additional index

```
CREATE TABLE notification (
    postid double,
    userid double,
    type text,
    message text,
    hasread boolean,
    postdate timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, postdate)
)  WITH  CLUSTERING ORDER BY (postdate DESC);

CREATE INDEX postid ON notification(postid);
```

Let's say I inserted several rows

```
select * from notification;

 userid | postdate                        | hasread | message                | postid | type
--------+---------------------------------+---------+------------------------+--------+---------
    104 | 2016-11-18 17:21:32.692000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  70521 | newpost
    104 | 2016-11-18 17:21:26.511000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  90521 | newpost
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:20:17.284000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  40521 | newpost
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:20:02.925000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  40521 | newpost
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:19:55.643000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  30521 | newpost
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:19:49.029000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  60521 | newpost
```

If I do simple queries i.e.

```
select * from notification where postid=40521;
```

then the result seems fine

```
userid | postdate                        | hasread | message                | postid | type
--------+---------------------------------+---------+------------------------+--------+---------
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:20:17.284000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  40521 | newpost
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:20:02.925000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  40521 | newpost
```

Or let's get a single row like this

```
select * from notification where postid=60521;
```

again the one single row seems fine

```
userid | postdate                        | hasread | message                | postid | type
--------+---------------------------------+---------+------------------------+--------+---------
    103 | 2016-11-18 17:19:49.029000+0000 |   False | Let\'s do it together! |  60521 | newpost
```

However, when I am updating the hasread row in one row, I am getting missing postdate error which is the clustering column

```
update notification set hasread=true where postid=60521 and userid=103;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Some clustering keys are missing: postdate"
```

I need to get the list in sorted order, that's the reason I have to use postdate for clustering column. 
However at the same time I need to update a specific row. I guess it's about the design but still couldn't figure it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating a row in Cassandra, you must provide your entire PRIMARY KEY.  That's essentially what that error message is telling you.  Remember, Cassandra is *NOT* a relational database, so you will *NOT* be able to update by `postid`.

Additionally, it is important to remember that Cassandra does not differentiate between an INSERT and an UPDATE.  As a specific row's uniqueness is determined by its complete PRIMARY KEY, you must have all PRIMARY KEY components present for all upserts.  Essentially, this is what you need to do:

```
UPDATE notification SET hasread=true 
  WHERE userid=103 AND postdate='2016-11-18 17:19:49.029+0000';
```

Also, it looks like `postid` is a high-cardinality column.  Therefore, calls relying on that secondary index are not going to perform well.  Like at all.  If you really need to query by `postid`, you should consider building an additional query table for that pattern.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it seems that I have to get first the postdate and update according to it

Answer (score 1):

**You can't update or delete with specifying non primary column to where clause.**

> The WHERE clause specifies the row or rows to be updated. To specify a row, the WHERE clause must provide a value for each column of the row's primary key. To specify more than one row, you can use the IN keyword to introduce a list of possible values. You can only do this for the last column of the primary key.

Let's update hasread  for postid=60521 and userid=103
First You need to select the postdate

```
SELECT postdate FROM notification where postid=60521 and userid=103;
```

You will get `postdate`. Now you can update the hasread field with userid and postdate

```
update notification set hasread=true where userid=103 and postdate=?;
```

Comment: Two things wrong with that last update statement.  One, `postid=60521` in the WHERE clause doesn't work.  Secondly, your millisecond precision is too high.  CQL will yield `unable to coerce...to a formatted date`.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake. Thanks @Aaron